# Is there a way to perform a function or assign a dynamic class to a pair of two components, skipping every two in an iteration from an array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a component I'm calling and iterating in the parent with an array of items. But after every two components the box-shadow is meant to be different. How do I give every pair of two components the same box shadow and the next two a different one? I hope you understand my question.

Initially, I thought I would just track it by the id or index and for any item with an index of 0 and 1, I'd give a certain box shadow, then the next pair 2, 3 would have a different one, then 4 and 5 a different one too; that sequence. But I'm having some problem with the implementation.

This is the parent

```
       <v-layout row wrap class="mt-3">
            <v-flex 
                xs12 v-for="(item,i) in plans"
                :key="i"
                >
                <plan-item :item="item" />
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
```

This is the data(plans) being iterated over

```
computed: {
        plans(){
            return this.$store.state.healthPlans
        }
    }
```

This is the plan-item child component

```
<div>
  <div :class="{'boxShadow1': isPairOne, 'boxShadow2': isPairTwo}"></div>
</div>

//It has the item prop
props: {
        item: {
            type: Object
        },
       }
```

The plan is that for every pair of two, they'll have the boxShadow1 class and the boxShadow2 would be for the next two and the cycle repeats itself no matter the number of items in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to pair up the indexes. You could use `i % 4 < 2`. The `i % 4` part will yield the sequence 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, ... and one pair will be 0 and 1 while the other pair will be 2 and 3.

Or if you prefer bitwise operators you could use `i & 2`, which would yield the sequence 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, ...

Where exactly you apply the shadow is up to you. e.g.

```html
<plan-item
  :item="item"
  :class="i % 4 < 2 ? 'boxShadow1' : 'boxShadow2'"
/>
```

```html
<plan-item
  :item="item"
  :class="i & 2 ? 'boxShadow2' : 'boxShadow1'"
/>
```

You could move this into the child using a suitable prop.

Comment: You're my new best friend! It worked! Thank you very much. To think that it was actually really straightforward. You're a genius!